# jquery function : is a radio checked / same id

Tags: jquery, function, radio-button, find, each

i have in a form a radio.

```
 <label class="radio inline" for="radios-BRE2b1">
    <input type="radio" name="radios-BRE2b1" id="BRE2b1" value="oui" required="" class="requiredvqradio">Oui</label>
<label class="radio inline" for="radios-BRE2b1">
    <input type="radio" name="radios-BRE2b1" id="BRE2b1" value="non" required="" class="requiredvqradio">Non</label>
<label class="radio inline" for="radios-BRE2b1">
    <input type="radio" name="radios-BRE2b1" id="BRE2b1" value="nsp" required="" class="requiredvqradio">Je ne sais pas</label>
```

ok, it's not valid... not unique id.

I want to make a function to know if one of the item is selected.

```
    function testemoi(name) {
    alert(name);
    $(this).find("#" + name).each(function (i, obj) {

        alert(obj.attr('name'));

        if (obj.is(":checked"))

        alert("ok");

    });


}
testemoi("radios-BRE2b1");
```

i think i have a syntax problem il my function but i cant see what's the problem.

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yn1h47nt/1/)

thanks for your help.

Comment: When your function should run? On page load, or...? Also, you are targeting id: find("#" + name), not name....

Answer (score 0):

As the use of identities is not valid, you can't use the `#` selector to find the elements. That would only find one of the elements, so you need to use the attribute selector instead.

Inside the `each` loop the object that you get as parameter is an element, not a jQuery object containing the element.

You call the function with the string `"radios-BRE2b1"`, but the id of the elements is `BRE2b1`.

I run the function on the click of a link so that you can select radio buttons before testing:

```js
function testemoi(name) {
  log(name);
  $("[id=" + name + "]").each(function (i, obj) {
    log($(obj).attr('name') + ': ' + $(obj).is(":checked"))
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.test').click(function(){
    testemoi("BRE2b1");
  });
});

function log(text){
  $('.log').append($('<div>').text(text));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="radio inline" for="radios-BRE2b1">
    <input type="radio" name="radios-BRE2b1" id="BRE2b1" value="oui" required="" class="requiredvqradio">Oui</label>
<label class="radio inline" for="radios-BRE2b1">
    <input type="radio" name="radios-BRE2b1" id="BRE2b1" value="non" required="" class="requiredvqradio">Non</label>
<label class="radio inline" for="radios-BRE2b1">
    <input type="radio" name="radios-BRE2b1" id="BRE2b1" value="nsp" required="" class="requiredvqradio">Je ne sais pas</label>
<br>
<a href="#" class="test">Click me to test</a>

<div class="log"></div>
```

Comment: Name is: name="radios-BRE2b1", so i guess selector could be something like: http://jsfiddle.net/yn1h47nt/2/

Answer (score 0):

When we are using # selector we always get the first element, we have to select all the element, by using either the name syntax

Added the sample button, on which if you click you could find, which radio button is selected.

```js
function testemoi(name) {
    
    $("input[name='"+name+"']").each(function (e) {
        var obj = $(this);
        alert(obj.attr('name'));

        if (obj.is(":checked"))
        alert("ok");

    });

}
testemoi("radios-BRE2b1");
//for demo click on demo button
$("#test").on("click",function(){testemoi("radios-BRE2b1");});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="radio inline" for="radios-BRE2b1">
    <input type="radio" name="radios-BRE2b1" id="BRE2b1" value="oui" required="" class="requiredvqradio">Oui</label>
<label class="radio inline" for="radios-BRE2b1">
    <input type="radio" name="radios-BRE2b1" id="BRE2b1" value="non" required="" class="requiredvqradio">Non</label>
<label class="radio inline" for="radios-BRE2b1">
    <input type="radio" name="radios-BRE2b1" id="BRE2b1" value="nsp" required="" class="requiredvqradio">Je ne sais pas</label>
    <button id="test">Test</button>
```

Hope it help

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

### You made two mistake in your code

- Selector should be like this

  ```
  $("input[name='" + name+"']:checked").each(function (i, obj) { // correct

  $(this).find("#" + name)// incorrect your code
  ```
- Get object value should inside $

  ```
  $(obj).attr('name'),$(obj).is(":checked") // correct

  obj.is(":checked") ,obj.attr('name') // incorrect your code
  ```

### Finally your corrected fiddle code should like below :

http://jsfiddle.net/yn1h47nt/5/

```
function testemoi(name) {debugger;
    alert(name);
    $("input[name='" + name+"']:checked").each(function (i, obj) {

        alert($(obj).attr('name'));

        if ($(obj).is(":checked"))

        alert("ok");

    });

}
testemoi("radios-BRE2b1");
```

### And You can check one of the radio selected easily like below condition :

http://jsfiddle.net/yn1h47nt/4/

```
  if (!$(".requiredvqradio:checked").val()) {
   alert('Nothing is checked!');
}
else {
  alert('one of radio button is checked!');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me.